# odoo 16 override js calendar function

Tags: javascript, odoo, fullcalendar, overriding

I want to override the function useFullCalendar in `/web/static/src/views/calendar/hooks.js.`
if I import:
`with import {useFullCalendar} from  "@web/static/src/views/calendar/hooks";` I always get

> Missing dependencies:     ['@web/static/src/views/calendar/hooks']

is it possible to override this function specially the function loadJsFiles inside and if how can override this function to load additional js files.

when I change the original function and load fullcalendars resource view files it works.im fine in python but really new to JavaScript.

thx for any help

I tried to import hooks.js

Comment: While I don't have an answer, I can make some suggestions that might help you get one. Try formatting your question better with codeblocks and examples. Also, try writing a more assertive title, for example "How can I override a hook function in odoo 16?". These kinds of changes usually helps a ton in getting people to take a closer look.